# Kafka Connect "Received unknown topic or partition error in fetch for partition..." Overlogging

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Our Kafka Connect server gets filled up very quickly by `connect.log`. The WARN that keeps appearing in the log file is:

`WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-2, groupId=connect-cluster] Received unknown topic or partition error in fetch for partition connect-statuses-2 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:1340)`

What may cause this warning and why it is logging as a spam?. It is getting logged more than 1000 times in a second, how can I stop that? Also is it safe to delete that consumer group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the brokers solved the issue, for now. Couldn't find the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

If you describe the `connect-statuses` topic, then look at partition 2, you'll see what replicas and leaders are available.

If no replicas are available, and no leader available, you'll see this warning message